# Unable to order Haystack/Whoosh results (and it's extremely slow)

Tags: django-haystack

I'm using [Haystack](http://www.haystacksearch.org) and [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca) to search a custom app with city data from the [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org) project.

I only have a small amount of the Geonames city data imported (22917 records). I'd like to order the results by a city's population and I'm having trouble getting good results.

When I use `order_by` on my `SearchQuerySet`, the results are extremely slow. It also orders properly with against the 'name' field but not 'population', so I think I'm probably just doing something wrong.

Here's the search index:

```
class EntryIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(indexed=False, model_attr='ascii_name')
    population = indexes.CharField(indexed=False, model_attr='population')
    django_id = indexes.CharField(indexed=False, model_attr='id')

    def get_model(self):
        return Entry

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Here's the template:

```
{{ object.ascii_name }}
{{ object.alternate_names }}
{{ object.country.name }}
{{ object.country.iso }}
{{ object.admin1_division.ascii_name }}
{{ object.admin1_division.name }}
{{ object.admin1_division.code }}
{{ object.admin2_division.ascii_name }}
{{ object.admin2_division.name }}
```

Here's the relevant view code:

```
query = request.GET.get('q', '')
results = SearchQuerySet().models(Entry).auto_query(query).order_by('population')
```

When I take the `order_by` off the query, it returns in less than one second. With it on, it takes almost 10 seconds to complete, and the results are not ordered by population. Ordering by name works, but it also takes ~10 seconds.

*Note: I've also tried with the built-in Haystack search view, and it's very slow when I try to order by population:*

```
qs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-population')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^demo2/$', SearchView(searchqueryset=qs)),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing nearly the same thing, and ordering works fast and correctly for me.

The only thing you're doing that differs significantly is:

```
query = request.GET.get('q', '')
results = SearchQuerySet().models(Entry).auto_query(query).order_by('population')
```

Since you specify a request, I'm assuming you've created your own view. You shouldn't need a custom view. I have this implemented with this in my urls.py:

```
from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import SearchView, search_view_factory

sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(MyModel).order_by('-weight')

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^search/$', search_view_factory(
        view_class=SearchView,
        template='search/search.html',
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=ModelSearchForm
    ), name='search'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I could not order results using order_by either. I was getting what seemed like a strange partial sorting. I eventually realised that the default ordering was by relevance ranking. The order_by I was using was presumably only sorting within each rank. This point is not really brought out in the Haystack documentation.

I guess the lesson is probably that if you want your results order to ignore relevance you need to post process your results before displaying them.

Probably a bit off topic, but I was a little surprised your index population field is a CharField. Does this match with your model?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm three years late, but recently I faced the same issue with a project I've been given.

I guess the only problem is the `indexed=False` parameter you are passing to the `population` CharField.

I fixed my problem by removing that.